# Learning dynamic memory allocation

Tags: c, dynamic-memory-allocation

i am a student and i try to teach myself code.
My question:

i have two structs:

```
struct1{
int a;
char name[20];}

struct 2{
struct struct1 *objekt;
int number;
double dNumber;}
```

I wanted to dynamically allocate memory in order to create at least one new Objekt(for lack of a better word). I know for example that i can allocate memory by using malloc or calloc. Which is fine. But how can i add a new object dynamically and via the console input, without defining a new struct? I am a complete novice and sorry. Thank you.

Comment: You need to study more. If we answer this you'll be back in 5 minutes to ask how to add two numbers ;)

Comment: I understand. Do you have a clue for me how to proceed?

Comment: @HerroPhong My advice is to get a good C book and start from there. You don't learn C from trial and error.

Comment: [You can try this](https://www.google.com/search?q=c+"dynamic+memory+allocation").

Comment: Hello @Broman do you have a suggestion?

Comment: Hello @HerroPhong. This link might serve you well [http://www.zentut.com/c-tutorial/c-dynamic-memory-allocation/](http://www.zentut.com/c-tutorial/c-dynamic-memory-allocation/). Good luck!

Comment: @eapetcho thank you

Comment: 1st thing to do is correct the code you have:  Make the 1st  `struct1` to be `struct struct1` and make `struct 2` to be `struct struct2`.

Comment: http://c-faq.com/sx2/index.html

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct Struct {
    int a;
    char name[20];
};

struct Struct struct1;

int main()
{
    struct Struct *struct1_p;
    struct1_p = &struct1;
    struct1.a = 1; 
    printf("struct1->a = %d\n", struct1_p->a);
    // Now let's create new structure dynamically
    struct Struct * struct2 =  malloc(sizeof(struct Struct));
    // Now check if the allocation succeeded?
    if(struct2 != NULL) { 
        //Success
        //struct2 now is a pointer to the memory which is reserved for struct2. 
        struct2->a = 2;
    } else {
        // Allocation failed
    }
    printf("struct2->a = %d\n", struct2->a);


    return 0;
}
```

This way, having the type of the desired object, you can dynamically create new object in the memory. Accessing the newly created object via pointer returned by `malloc`.
Remember that malloc returns `void*`, no need for explicitly cast.

Comment: [It's better not to cast the result of malloc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc). There is little sense in explicit casting a `void *` pointer.

Comment: @Hairi
This is helpful and adds a lot to my understanding. Thank you very much.

Comment: @KamilCuk I think you are right. Though I have seen the explicit cast many times. I don't know why would they do that. I changed the answer.

Comment: @HerroPhong I am glad to here that it helped you.

Comment: @HerroPhong You can check as correct answer if you find it satisfactory